# PyQt5 get QErrorMessage to block Mainwindow

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt5

In PyQt5, and I believe retroactively at least to 4, if a QMessageBox is initialized with MainWindow as the parent it will block any input to MainWindow until the MessageBox is accepted, closed, etc...

However, if you initialize a QErrorMessage using MainWindow as parent this behavior does not occur. Is there a way to pass some sort of window parameter to QErrorMessage such that it blocks the parent window until it is closed?

n.b. I realize that I can make a QMessageBox behave and appear like a QErrorMessage. I would just like to know if the above described behavior is possible.

Comment: as QMessageBox inherits QDialog, you can try to set `setModal(True)` to have the expected behavior. You can also try to run the `QErrorMessage` with `.exec_()`. Both should work in your case.

Comment: @SyedElec I had been using `.exec_()` which is why I was surprised.

Comment: Did you try to force the modality of the dialog with `setModal(True)` ? `exec_()` should do the trick unless you modified the modality of the dialog using `setWindowModality()`. Can you show a simple example ?

Comment: `setModal(True)` didn't work

Comment: Ok then try to change the modality of the `QErrorMessage` dialog and force it with `setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)`. If it does not work, we need to see your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your `QErrorMessage` as modal using `setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        emsg = QtWidgets.QErrorMessage(self)
        emsg.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)

        cwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(cwidget)
        lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show message')
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: emsg.showMessage('Message: ' + lineedit.text()))
        layout.addWidget(lineedit)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setCentralWidget(cwidget)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: So I tried both `setModal(True)` and `setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)` and neither worked. Is it possible that this is the result of something being set improperly on the mainwindow? Unfortunately I am trying to clean up someone else's project so I am not completely sure about all of the settings in the `Ui_MainWindow` class.

Comment: Does the above example work for you? Make sure `MainWindow` is assigned as the parent to your `QMessageBox` or it won't block. I'm not sure if any settings on the `MainWindow` can affect this behaviour.

Comment: Aww man, so dumb. Your code worked and made me realize what was wrong. I was calling `showMessage()` before setting modality. I didn't realize `showMessage()` was effectively calling `show()` as well, although I should have realized as much from the name. My order was `showMessage()`, `setModal()` then calling either `show()` or `exec_()` afterwards.